# How can I show MUI TextField/FormControl error message with a left red border only when there is an error?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, yup

When validation fails, I want the error message and TextField to look this way:
[Desired result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgNZl.png).

So far, using MUI, I'm getting close to the desired result. Here is where I'm at: [My progress image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is0Eg.png), but I'm not sure how to show the red border only if there is validation error.

In addition to that, I feel like I'm doing a lot custom style to make this look that way.

```
sx={{
              fontSize: 20,
              color: 'black',
            }}
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong. So please let know how I can improve it.

Here is my code:  https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-pond-5fg5z9?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to to show the red border only if there is validation error change this code:

```
<FormControl
  sx={{
    "&.MuiFormControl-root": {
      borderLeft: "3px solid red"
    }
  }}
```

To this:

```
<FormControl
  sx={formik.touched.ssn && formik.errors.ssn !== undefined && {
    "&.MuiFormControl-root": {
      borderLeft: "3px solid red"
    }
  }}
```

Basically you should conditionally apply style which adds red border.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I found for this was:

```
Another solution I found was this: 
sx={{
            '&.MuiFormControl-root:has(.Mui-error)': {
              // if a child of FormControl has class Mui-error apply css to FormControl
              borderLeft: '3px solid red',
            },
          }}
```